# My button isn't taking a value from and input in JS React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

okay so I want to enter a name into the field and click addname to add it to a list, it mostly works except when you press add it just adds a bullet point to the list, so its blank. Heres my code

```
import React from 'react'

const List = (props) => <ul> { _.map(props.nameList, (name) => {
      return <li>{name}</li>})}</ul> 

export default class NameList extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {nameList: [ "Richard" ]}
    }

    render() {
        var allNames =  {nameList: [ "Richard" ]}
        return (
            <div>
              <input type ="text" value= {this.props.name}/>
              <button onClick={() => { this.setState({ nameList: _.concat(this.state.nameList, this.props.name)})}}>AddName</button>
              <List nameList={this.state.nameList}/>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Has maybe something todo with "this.props", try to wrap the value in a state of the class NameList.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your text input actually has no way of tying its value back to anything so when you click the button `this.props.name` is undefined. You would want to also have a state for the name of the person you want to add that way when you call `setState` you can tie it to that value. Here is updated working code.

```
import React from 'react';

const List = props => <ul> { _.map(props.nameList, name => <li>{name}</li>)}</ul>;

export default class NameList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { nameList: ['Richard'], nameToAdd: '' };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ nameList: _.concat(prevState.nameList, this.state.nameToAdd), nameToAdd: '' }));
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={ this.state.nameToAdd } onChange={ e => this.setState({ nameToAdd: e.target.value }) } />
        <button onClick={ this.handleClick }>AddName</button>
        <List nameList={ this.state.nameList } />
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

here is also the working pen http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/OpWyqX

primary difference is that i added an `onChange` to the input and added a `nameToAdd` state to the NameList component which gets updated whenever the textinput changes. Once you add a name it clears the `nameToAdd` state.

I also used a callback function for `setState` which is waht you want to do when you are relying on the components current state to decide how that portion of state should be updated.

The react docs goes over that here
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

> It's also possible to pass a function with the signature
>   function(state, props) => newState. This enqueues an atomic update
>   that consults the previous value of state and props before setting any
>   values. For instance, suppose we wanted to increment a value in state
>   by props.step: